# SESSION destroy after page reload

Tags: php, session

I have created two php pages.

First Page `index.php` include

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

// Get a value.
$_SESSION['id'] = 324;

?> 
<a href="session.php?id=1">forward</a>
```

Second page `session.php` include

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

My question is if I press F5 button for approximately 5 seconds the `SESSION` will be destroyed is it normal or no? Should be `SESSION` destroyed after a lot of reloads?

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: What should I do about it?